# Removing element from array in component state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to find the best way to remove an element from an array in the state of a component.  Since I should not modify the `this.state` variable directly, is there a better way (more concise) to remove an element from an array than what I have here?:

```
  onRemovePerson: function(index) {
    this.setState(prevState => { // pass callback in setState to avoid race condition
      let newData = prevState.data.slice() //copy array from prevState
      newData.splice(index, 1) // remove element
      return {data: newData} // update state
    })
  },
```

Thank you.

**updated**

This has been updated to use the callback in setState. This should be done when referencing the current state while updating it.

Comment: Take a look at ImmutableJS from Facebook that works good with React. [link](http://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/)

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code. In fact it's very idiomatic way to do it.

Answer (score 160, accepted):

The cleanest way to do this that I've seen is with `filter`:

```
removeItem(index) {
  this.setState({
    data: this.state.data.filter((_, i) => i !== index)
  });
}
```

Comment: @HussienK the `_` is sometimes used to represent an unused argument. Here, it's the current item in the array.

Comment: Amazing. I'm using .filter all the time but never considered to use it in this situation. :D

Comment: This is clean code, however, for large arrays, this method is slow. Reason being, it loops through the entire array to find an index that looks to already be determined.

Comment: @MattEllis Since React's state updates are immutable anyway, you're going to be incurring O(n) in the size of the list to copy it in any case. I would be surprised if this were a significant performance hit.

Comment: @ephrion The solution looks awesome. Unfortunately for me the last index and first index from the array are not deleting with this method. Do you any clue ? 

Comment: This is most simple and clean solution.

Comment: Evaluating `this.state` as input to `this.setState()` , even immutably, is not recommended. please see my answer above for a reference to the official React docs on this topic.

Comment: I used immutability-helper as Rich Warrior suggests, but what is the reason you are suggesting filter instead of splice?

Answer (score 85):

You could use the [`update()` immutability helper from `react-addons-update`](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/update.html), which effectively does the same thing under the hood, but what you're doing is fine.

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
  data: update(prevState.data, {$splice: [[index, 1]]})
}))
```

Comment: Much simpler example than the one you linked to :)

Comment: `react-addons-update` is now deprecated (2016). `immutability-helper` is available as a replacement. https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper

Also please see my answer below regarding not mutating this.state directly inside this.setState().

Answer (score 72):

I believe referencing `this.state` inside of `setState()` is discouraged ([State Updates May Be Asynchronous](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous)).

The docs recommend using `setState()` with a callback function so that prevState is passed in at runtime when the update occurs. So this is how it would look:

**Using Array.prototype.filter without ES6**

```
removeItem : function(index) {
  this.setState(function(prevState){
    return { data : prevState.data.filter(function(val, i) {
      return i !== index;
    })};
  });
}
```

**Using Array.prototype.filter with ES6 Arrow Functions**

```
removeItem(index) {
  this.setState((prevState) => ({
    data: prevState.data.filter((_, i) => i !== index)
  }));
}
```

**Using immutability-helper**

```
import update from 'immutability-helper'
...
removeItem(index) {
  this.setState((prevState) => ({
    data: update(prevState.data, {$splice: [[index, 1]]})
  }))
}
```

**Using Spread**

```
function removeItem(index) {
  this.setState((prevState) => ({
    data: [...prevState.data.slice(0,index), ...prevState.data.slice(index+1)]
  }))
}
```

Note that in each instance, regardless of the technique used, `this.setState()` is passed a callback, *not* an object reference to the old `this.state`;

Comment: This is the correct answer, see also [The Power of Not Mutating Data](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/optimizing-performance.html#the-power-of-not-mutating-data)

Comment: Examples using the prevState callback with various techniques added.

Comment: what if i do it like this?


`this.setState({
    data: [...this.state.data.slice(0, index), ...this.state.data.slice(index + 1)]
 });`


is it wrong to use `this.state` instead of the `prevState` callback option showed by @user1628461?

Comment: This is the best solution, although not simplest

Comment: thanks, using spread its possible to update an element in middle too instead of deleting it, that's what i needed.

Comment: I am stuck with this same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74017672/state-not-getting-update-on-deleting-one-object-from-an-array-in-usestate

Please have a look at this once

Answer (score 26):

Here is a way to remove the element from the array in the state using ES6 spread syntax.

```
onRemovePerson: (index) => {
  const data = this.state.data;
  this.setState({ 
    data: [...data.slice(0,index), ...data.slice(index+1)]
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This feels like the most natural way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

I want to chime in here even though this question has already been [answered correctly by @pscl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41644112/9571755) in case anyone else runs into the same issue I did.  Out of the 4 methods give I chose to use the es6 syntax with arrow functions due to it's conciseness and lack of dependence on external libraries:

**Using Array.prototype.filter with ES6 Arrow Functions**

```
removeItem(index) {
  this.setState((prevState) => ({
    data: prevState.data.filter((_, i) => i != index)
  }));
}
```

As you can see I made a slight modification to ignore the type of index (`!==` to `!=`) because in my case I was retrieving the index from a string field.

Another helpful point if you're seeing weird behavior when removing an element on the client side is to **NEVER use the index of an array as the key for the element**:

```
// bad
{content.map((content, index) =>
  <p key={index}>{content.Content}</p>
)}
```

When React diffs with the virtual DOM on a change, it will look at the keys to determine what has changed. So if you're using indices and there is one less in the array, it will remove the last one. Instead, use the id's of the content as keys, like this.

```
// good
{content.map(content =>
  <p key={content.id}>{content.Content}</p>
)}
```

The above is an excerpt from [this answer from a related post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35459630).

Happy Coding Everyone!

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in a comment to ephrion's answer above, filter() can be slow, especially with large arrays, as it loops to look for an index that appears to have been determined already. This is a clean, but inefficient solution.

As an alternative one can simply 'slice' out the desired element and concatenate the fragments.

```
var dummyArray = [];    
this.setState({data: dummyArray.concat(this.state.data.slice(0, index), this.state.data.slice(index))})
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this function, if you want to remove the element (without index)

```
removeItem(item) {
  this.setState(prevState => {
    data: prevState.data.filter(i => i !== item)
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make the code more readable with a one line helper function:

```
const removeElement = (arr, i) => [...arr.slice(0, i), ...arr.slice(i+1)];
```

then use it like so:

```
this.setState(state => ({ places: removeElement(state.places, index) }));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion,in your code instead of using `let newData = prevState.data` you could use spread which is introduced in ES6 that is you can use`let newData = ...prevState.data`  for copying array

Three dots ... represents [Spread Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) or [Rest Parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters),

It allows an array expression or string or anything which can be iterating to be expanded in places where zero or more arguments for function calls or elements for array are expected.

Additionally you can delete item from array with following

```
onRemovePerson: function(index) {
  this.setState((prevState) => ({
    data: [...prevState.data.slice(0,index), ...prevState.data.slice(index+1)]
  }))
}
```

Hope this contributes!!

Answer (score 0):

In react `setState`

```
const [array, setArray] = useState<any>([]);
//element you want to remove
let temp = array.filter((val: number) => {
    return val !== element;
 });
setArray(temp);
```

Answer (score -2):

**Here is a simple way to do it:**

```
removeFunction(key){
  const data = {...this.state.data}; //Duplicate state.
  delete data[key];                  //remove Item form stateCopy.
  this.setState({data});             //Set state as the modify one.
}
```

Hope it Helps!!!

Comment: Care to explain?

Comment: I think it is because `delete` removes item but indexes don't get updated and therefore this would not be good approach for regular needs.