# How to remove an element from array state in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an array in firebase with root branch named `Rooms` and a state in the app named `rooms` (array). I was able to make it so when user enter new room name and press submit, it is being added to the end of `Rooms` object.

[image: screenshot of firebase database]

I wanted to implement a delete method so when user clicks on `x` button next to room name, it will delete that element from the state and from firebase, but I have no success implementing it.

My starting point is a thread from [SO similarly titled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29527385/removing-element-from-array-in-component-state). I fail to implement the code on the `<li>` component that works. This is what I have:

Chatroom.js

```
  handleRemove(index) {
    var array =  this.state.rooms.slice();
    array.splice(index, 1);
    this.setState({
      rooms: array
    })
  }
  ...
  render(){
    <div><DisplayChatrooms rooms={this.state.rooms} handleRemove={this.handleRemove.bind(this)} /></div>
```

DisplayChatrooms.js

```
class DisplayChatrooms extends React.Component{
  render(){
    console.log('handleRemove: ', this.props.handleRemove); //this prints out the handleRemove function just fine
    var rooms = this.props.rooms.map(function(room, index){
      return (
        <li key={index}>{room} <a href="#">x</a></li>
      )
    })
    return(
      <div>
        <ul>
          {rooms}
        </ul>
      </div>
```

When I modified the `li` to include `handleRemove`, it shows this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined`.

```
<li key={index}>{room} <a href="#" onClick={this.props.handleRemove}>x</a></li>
```

How can I implement a method that allows user to remove that element when x is clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 this.props.rooms.map(function(room, index){
  return (
    <li key={index}>{room} <a href="#">x</a></li>
  )
})
```

the "li" is in the scope of `function(room, index)`, that the `this` is point to global in this case `window` object, thats why props is not on `this`, you can use es6 fat arrow

```
this.props.rooms.map((room, index) => {})
```

or old school method

```
var self = this;
this.props.rooms.map(function() { self.props.handleRemove })
```