# Problems with understanding of array.map() scope in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scope

I have done an  array.map() that loop through json file (goods.json). Then I want to make some manipulations with it (want to delete item from this array in removeCard(obj) method for example). Render is ok but **the problem is that I don't understand why I can't see shoppingCardsJSX array in removeCard(obj) method, always get underfined.** I have read answers  in [How to delete a ToDo Item onClick in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44831916/how-to-delete-a-todo-item-onclick-in-react) and [Remove item from array in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48077103/remove-item-from-array-in-react) but unfortunately I didn't understand how it works. Can you please help me find out what I'm doing wrong ? Hope this part of code can illustrate my problem,

```js
import { sample } from 'rxjs/internal/operators';
import React from 'react';
import ShoppingCard from './ShoppingCard';
import goods from './goods.json';

export default class ShoppingCards extends React.Component {
    constructor (props){
        super(props);
    }
    removeCard(obj){
        console.log("fireeeee");
        console.log(obj);
        console.log(this.shoppingCardsJSX);
    }
    render() {
        console.log("render");
        let shoppingCardsJSX = goods.map((good) => {
            return (
                <ShoppingCard
                    key = {good.id }
                    goodId = {good.id}
                    src = {good.src}
                    price = {good.price}
                    onRemoveCard={this.removeCard}
                />
            );
        });
        console.log(shoppingCardsJSX);
        return shoppingCardsJSX;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Are you sure *goods* contains anything?  Can you console.log it to be sure?

Comment: yes, it contains

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you never set `this.shoppingCardsJSX` and also you also should use `this.removeCard.bind(this)` instead of `this.removeCard` as a prop, because then it can reference `this` when it is called.

```js
import { sample } from 'rxjs/internal/operators';
import React from 'react';
import ShoppingCard from './ShoppingCard';
import goods from './goods.json';

export default class ShoppingCards extends React.Component {
    constructor (props){
        super(props);
    }
    removeCard(obj){
        console.log("fireeeee");
        console.log(obj);
        console.log(this.shoppingCardsJSX);
    }
    render() {
        console.log("render");
        this.shoppingCardsJSX = goods.map((good) => {
            return (
                <ShoppingCard
                    key = {good.id }
                    goodId = {good.id}
                    src = {good.src}
                    price = {good.price}
                    onRemoveCard={this.removeCard.bind(this)}
                />
            );
        });
        console.log(this.shoppingCardsJSX);
        return this.shoppingCardsJSX;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @prostyash awesome glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like running the code snippet is returning an error because you're never actually setting `shoppingCardsJSX` to the component. Your `console.log(this.shoppingCardsJSX);` statement is causing it to error out

You can always try wrapping it in a div:

```
import { sample } from 'rxjs/internal/operators';
import React from 'react';
import ShoppingCard from './ShoppingCard';
import goods from './goods.json';

export default class ShoppingCards extends React.Component {
    constructor (props){
        super(props);
    }
    removeCard(obj){
        console.log("fireeeee");
        console.log(obj);
    }
    render() {
        return (
           <div>
             {
              goods && goods.map((good) => {
                return (
                  <ShoppingCard
                    key = {good.id }
                    goodId = {good.id}
                    src = {good.src}
                    price = {good.price}
                    onRemoveCard={this.removeCard}
                  />
                );
              });
            }
        </div>
      )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use an arrow function to bind the `this` keyword to `removeCard` function like this

```
removeCard = (obj) => {
        console.log("fireeeee");
        console.log(obj);
        console.log(this.shoppingCardsJSX);
    }
```

The other way is to do this

```
<ShoppingCard
    key = {good.id }
    goodId = {good.id}
    src = {good.src}
    price = {good.price}
    onRemoveCard={this.removeCard.bind(this}
/>
```

However don't mix the two.

Answer (score 0):

Use Arrow function as they are binded by default. you dont need to bind these arrow functions.

```
 removeCard=(obj)=>{
        console.log("fireeeee");
        console.log(obj);
        console.log(this.shoppingCardsJSX);
    }
```