# How to add event handler for deleting a single item from the list?

Tags: reactjs

I have the following code, and I want to add an even handler for detecting when delete button is clicked and then remove the specific item from list.

**Favorites.js**

```
 constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            movies: []
        };

        this.clearSaved = this.clearSaved.bind(this);
        this.handleDelete = this.handleDelete.bind(this);
    }
```

**MovieList.js**

```
export default ({ movies }) => {
    return(
        <div id="saved-movies-list">
        <ul className="saved-movies-list">
        { movies.map(movie => <li key={ movie.imdbID }><Movie movie={ movie } /></li>) }
        </ul>
        </div>
    )
};
```

**Movie.js**

```
const Movie = ({movie}) => {
     return (<div className="movie-card" id={movie.imdbID}>     
          {
               // eslint-disable-next-line
               movie.poster == 'N/A' ? 
               <div className="movie-card-poster missing">
               <img className="d-block h-100" src={movie_poster} alt="" /> 
               </div>
               :
               <div className="movie-card-poster">
               <img className="d-block h-100" src={movie.poster} alt="" />
               </div>
          }
          <div className="body">
               <div style={{ maxWidth: '80%' }}>
                    <h5 class="card-title">{movie.title}</h5>
               </div>
               <p className="text-secondary">{ movie.year }</p>
               {!movie.runtime ? "" : <p className="text-secondary">{ movie.runtime }</p>}
               <p className="plot">{movie.description}</p>
               <a href="#" className="delete-movie" title="Remove this movie"><FontAwesomeIcon icon="minus-circle" size="1x" /></a>
          </div>
     </div>)
}
```

**I need to attach event to this line:**

```
       <a href="#" className="delete-movie" title="Remove this movie"><FontAwesomeIcon icon="minus-circle" size="1x" /></a>
```

But, I do NOT know how to? Writing this.props. ... does not work!

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to delete a ToDo Item onClick in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44831916/how-to-delete-a-todo-item-onclick-in-react)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In `Movie` component:**

Add a callback prop in your `Movie` component, call whatever you like e.g.: `onDelete`.

Then add `handleClick` handler that calls your callback prop,

```js
const handleClick = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();

  props.onDelete(); // This callback is coming from your `Movie` props.
}
```

and pass it to your anchor element's `onClick` attribute.

```js
<a
  href="#"
  className="delete-movie"
  title="Remove this movie"
  onClick={handleClick}
>
  <FontAwesomeIcon icon="minus-circle" size="1x" />
</a>
```

**In `MovieList` component:**

Add a callback prop in your `MovieList` component and call it `onDeleteMovie`.

```js
export default (props) => {
```

Then pass it in your `Movie`'s `onDelete` prop like this:

```js
{props.movies.map((movie, index) => 
  <li key={index}> // since imdbID is not unique after all use the index
    <Movie
     movie={movie}
     onDelete={() => props.onDeleteMovie(index)}
    />
  </li>
)}
```

**In `Favorites` component:**

Add a `handleDelete` method in `Favorites` component that looks like this.

```js
handleDelete(index) {
  const movies = [...this.state.movies];

  movies.splice(index, 1);

  this.setState({ movies });
}
```

and pass it to your `MovieList`s `onDeleteMovie` prop.

```js
<MovieList
  movies={this.state.movies}
  onDeleteMovie={this.handleDelete}
/>
```

Comment: Ioannis, my movie.js looks like this now, `const Movie = (props) => {`

Comment: I also had a mistake, I wrote Movies instead of MovieList and passed the movies from state. I guess you have something similar to Favorites component.

Comment: Ioannis, MovieList has also props

Comment: I apologize for thi

Comment: I tried adding, `this.state.movies.filter(movie => movie.imdbID != imdbID);`

Comment: Don't worry, I'm updating that too.

Comment: I am using `<li key={ movie.imdbID }>`

Comment: Ioanns, it removes everything?

Comment: When I click, to remove one single item, it removes all?

Comment: Well, do they have common imdbID?

Comment: Good question, I will check now.

Comment: Yes, you were correct. Can I ask, why aren't the specific items removed from the array?

Comment: I am printing the state, after, and it still shows me the items, even if it is removed in the view? setState does not seem to work?

Comment: It is expected then that all items are removed. This is why I work with index when I don't know the data. I can change the answer to work with index one last time.

Comment: I've updated the answer one last time. Try it this way. Good luck. :-)

Comment: Ioannis, `this.setState({ movies });` it does not seem to make any changes? Do you know why?

Comment: Can you share your movies state?

Comment: `this.state = {
            movies: []
        };` that's in the constructor of **favorites.js**

Comment: Then I am doing what you told me!

Comment: Here's something, that seems wrong, `onDelete={props.onDeleteMovie(movie.imdbId)}` in my <li> during map, having it like that, it will not render anything. Changing it to: `onDelete={() => props.onDeleteMovie(movie.imdbId)}` and you'll get nothing working.

Comment: I figured out the problem in the end! Thanks a lot dude.

Answer (score 0):

```js
export default ({ movies }) => {
    const handleDelete = (id) => {
      // write your deleting logic here with item id
    }
    return(
        <div id="saved-movies-list">
          <ul className="saved-movies-list">
          {
             movies.map(movie => 
               <li key={ movie.imdbID }>
                 <Movie
                  movie={ movie }
                  onDelete={() => handleDelete(movie.imbID)}
                 />
               </li>
             )
           }
          </ul>
        </div>
    )
};
```

in Moive.js

```js
const Movie = ({movie, onDelete}) => {
  return (
    ...
    <a href="#" className="delete-movie" title="Remove this movie" 
      onClick= {onDelete}
    > 
     <FontAwesomeIcon icon="minus-circle" size="1x" />
    </a>
    ...
  )
}
```

I passed the `handleDelete` with parameter item id to every child component as onDelete function.

Comment: TypeError: props.handleDelete is not a function

Answer (score 0):

For the event handler, you can use simple `onClick` event like this:

```
{ movies.map(movie => <li onClick={()=>handleClick(movie.imdbID)} key={ movie.imdbID }><Movie movie={ movie } /></li>) }
```

Then you should write your handleClick function, which you want to delete the movie. 
Now, there's a lot of ways you can take that deletion. But lets asume you just don't want it to render. Then you should manage an array/collections of `imdbID's` you don't want to render and using it in your render event.

Using React Hooks:

```
export default ({ movies }) => {

    const [removeList, setRemoveList] = useState([]);
    const handleClick = (id) => setRemoveList([...removeList, id]);   

    return(
        <div id="saved-movies-list">
            <ul className="saved-movies-list">
                { movies.map(movie => (!removeList.includes(movie.imdbID)) && <li onClick={()=>handleClick(movie.imdbID)} key={ movie.imdbID }><Movie movie={ movie } /></li>) }
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In the file that you are declaring `movies`, also declare this function

---

```
   const deleteMovie = key => this.setState({ movies: this.state.movies.filter(movie => movie.imdbID != key })
```

---

Pass it as props to `Movie`, and use like

---

```
  onClick ={()=> deleteMovie(movie.imbdID)}
```

Comment: TypeError: can't access property "setState" of undefined

Comment: TypeError: props.handleDelete is not a function