# Remove specific product based on multiple factors

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to remove the specific product a user is clicking on.

So far, when you are trying to remove a product from the cart it removes based on the ID the product has. Though, I need it to check size, color, and ID. I don't want it to remove both "Product A, size M" and "Product A, size L" if the user is only clicking on size M.

So for example:
[image]

If I try to remove the "size M" one, it should `only` remove the "size M" one, not the "size L" as well (as both of them have the same ID).

Here is my code where the deletion of a product is:

```
const removeItemHandler = (e) => {
    let id = e.currentTarget.getAttribute("itemid");
    let size = e.currentTarget.getAttribute("size");
    let color = e.currentTarget.getAttribute("color");

    const clonedCartItems = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(cartItems));

    // Here is where I am trying to filter out the product. So it will only take the one the user is 
    clicking on
    let newCart = clonedCartItems.filter(
      (elem) => elem.id !== id && elem.size !== size
    );

    setCartItems(newCart);
  };
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using React JS, then question like this has already been asked,
trick is to pass the index, while calling removeItemHandler

[Removing element from array in component state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29527385/removing-element-from-array-in-component-state)

`e.currentTarget.getAttribute("itemid");` this code is dependent on the data,
Today your logic dependent on `size` and `color`, tomorrow it might be something else

**Scalable code** : You can assign the `UUID (probably v4)` while adding the stuffs to the cart and then setting it over attribute (or passing over callback with above approach), then taking the id and finding it.

```
let id = e.currentTarget.getAttribute("UUID");
```

with one line this can be generic.

**sample code**

[codesandbox.io/s/delete-items-from-cart-g9qm5?file=/src/App.js](https://codesandbox.io/s/delete-items-from-cart-g9qm5?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Not really following along, UUID, in this case, is what? Or do you mean that I could set the id, size and color in "one line" then compare it? So it would look something like `idMblack`?

Comment: the function which is responsible for adding stuffs to cart, should add one more property, call it as UUID or something, 
while rendering the delete button, passback the uuid : `removeItemHandler(e,uuid)`, then your logic will be based on a single Id's not based on the data it holds

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/delete-items-from-cart-g9qm5?file=/src/App.js
use this link, i have written a sample code

Answer (score 0):

```
let newCart = clonedCartItems.filter(
      (elem) => {
         if(elem.id == id) {
            return elem.size !== size;
         }else
         return elem.id !== id
       }
);
```